# What does blogpost's rss feed pagination url look like?

Tags: url, url-parameters, blogspot

I am aware the to get to a blogspot blog's rss feed you go to

```
blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
```

But how do you get the second page of the feed?

I am aware that other blogs use the query parameter `?paged=2`. Is there a similar query parameter that does the same thing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Does someone know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After circling back to the relavent project I found the answer to my own question via a quick google search.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#RetrievingWithQuery

> start-index
>
> The 1-based index of the first result to be retrieved (for paging).

the second page would look like `blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?start-index=2`