# How to parse the RSS feed with multiple pages by using feedparser

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python.

I'm using the feedparser for parsing the RSS feeds, and it works great in the begining.

However, if the web is truncated into multiple pages, which means you can click the 'Next' or 'Previous' button to view the page from the web, you only can parse the first page by using feedparser.

How can I parse the rest of the pages?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What pages do you mean? Different URLs? Where to click? You did not show your code, sample (problematic) RSS source, or even screenshot of the problem...

Comment: [RSS URL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsoftintuneprod/threads?outputAs=rss)  [Website URL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=microsoftintuneprod&sort=lastpostdesc&brandIgnore=true&page=2)

Comment: `import feedparser` `d = feedparser.parse(url)`

Comment: This question is not related to the feedparser or even python. It is about specific forum and its pagination in RSS feed. Some forums have documented pagination: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953611/what-does-blogposts-rss-feed-pagination-url-look-like But not all. You have to find (if possible) URLs for different pages for your RSS feed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.